# How do I save an image in Matlab with axes but without plotting?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, axes

I have an image I that I want to save with axes on it.

```
    imwrite(I,jet,'image.jpg');
```

will save the image.

```
    I = image;

    RI = imref2d(size(I));
    RI.XWorldLimits = [xmin xmax];
    RI.YWorldLimits = [ymin ymax];

    figure(1);
    imshow(I,RI,jet);
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('y');

    print(1,'-djpeg','image.jpg');
```

will plot the image with axes on a figure and then save it with axes.

I want to save the image with axes, without plotting it in a figure first. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is for the figure not to be seen by the user, the easiest way is to create the figure and set its `'visible'` property to `'off'`:

```
I = image;

RI = imref2d(size(I));
RI.XWorldLimits = [xmin xmax];
RI.YWorldLimits = [ymin ymax];

figure(1);
set(1,'visible','off') %// add this line to make figure not visible
imshow(I,RI,jet);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');

print(1,'-djpeg','image.jpg');
```